# finding point spectrum and spectrum set for a operator on $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $T:\ell^2\to \ell^2$ be defined by $y=Tx$, $x=(\xi_j)$,
>   $y=(\eta_j)$, $\eta_j=\alpha_j\xi_j$, where $(\alpha_j)$ is dense in
>   $[0,1]$. Find point spectrum $\sigma_P(T)$ and spectrum $\sigma(T)$ of $T$.

Point spectrum of an operator is the set of its eigenvalues. So we have $$Tx=y \\ \implies T(\xi_j)=\eta_j \\ \implies T(\xi_j)=\alpha_j\xi_j \\ \implies (T-\alpha_jI)\xi_j=0$$ which shows that $\{\alpha_j\}$ is the set of eigenvalues of $T$, hence the point spectrum is $\{\alpha_j\}$ for all $j$. Now we see that on the set $\rho(T)=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\alpha_j\}=\{\beta_j\}$, $(T-\beta_jI)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded. But in order to $\rho(T)$ be a resolvent set, $(T-\beta_jI)^{-1}$ must exist on $\rho(T)$ as a dense subset of $[0,1]$. It is certainly given that $(\alpha_j)$ is dense in $[0,1]$. But does this imply $\rho(T)=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{\alpha_j\}$ is also dense in $[0,1]$? If so, $\sigma(T)=\{\alpha_j\}$ will be spectrum of $T$. But I am not sure whether this approach is right. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $(T-\beta_j I)^{-1}$ is not bounded if $\beta_j\in [0,1]\setminus \{\alpha\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Add to previous comment: the spectrum is closed, so you should take the closure of the set of points of the point spectrum. Since $l_2$ -- is hilbert space, the remainder of the spectrum is a continuous spectrum.

Comment: So $\sigma(T)=\overline{\{\alpha_j\}}=[0,1]$?

Comment: That's correct, yes.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou, how can we conclude that $\left( T - \beta I \right)^{-1}$ is not bounded for $\beta \in \left[ 0, 1 \right] \setminus \left\lbrace \alpha_j \right\rbrace_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: @aniruddhaDeshmukh Just use the fact that the $\alpha_j$ are assumed dense in $[0,1]$.